# Greedy Algorithm Approach

Tags: algorithm, sorting, optimization, schedule, greedy

So i have this problem where a food place with only 1 delivery man has to deliver food to customers. It has all the orders in the morning and at noon he will start delivering. Each customer *i* has *ti*(time for food preparation and delivery) and *vi*(value of importance to the food place). So if customer *j* is the first customer his order will be delivered in time *Xj = tj*. If customer's *f* food get prepared and delivered after customer *j*, his food will be delivered in time *Xf = Xj + tf*. About the importance factor, the aim of the delivery man is to have the least sum of lateness where lateness is: sum *from i=1 to n* (where n number of customers) of *vi* * *Xi*.

For example:

I have this list of customers

```
CUSTOMER        DISTANCE        IMPORTANCE
 1              10              8
 2              1               8
 3              5               7
 4              5               3
 5              3               7
```

If i sort them by delivering each time to the nearest customer without taking into consideration his importance i will get the sum of:

(if 2 have the same distance then choose one with most importance)

```
The sum by distance is :333
(8*1+7*4+7*9+3*14+8*24 = 333)
```

And this will be the order of the delivery

```
 CUSTOMER       DISTANCE        IMPORTANCE
 2              1               8
 5              3               7
 3              5               7
 4              5               3
 1              10              8
```

I also tried selecting each time the most important customer with the sum being:

(if 2 have the same importance then choose one with least distance)

```
The sum by importance is :399
(8*1+8*11+7*14+7*19+3*24 = 399)
```

And the order of the deliveries:

```
 CUSTOMER       DISTANCE        IMPORTANCE
 2              1               8
 1              10              8
 5              3               7
 3              5               7
 4              5               3
```

So in this scenario selecting always the closest one did calculate a smaller sum than the selecting always the most important one, but this doesn't work every time. I have to come up with something that will give me the optimal sum in every given list. I know that both distance and importance have to be taken into consideration but i cannot figure out the formula that i will have to apply to always get the least sum. If someone knows any greedy algorithm technique that will be in use in this scenario i would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that a greedy algorithm (that always finds an optimum solution) exists? Because this problem seems to be designed as an exercise in dynamic programming.

Comment: Well i am asked to design a greedy algorithm, so there must be a solution i guess. But i can't figure it out. I'm kind of new to algorithms. I guess that there would be similar popular problems.

Comment: The best order for the example is 2,5,3,1,4 with a sum of 323. The distances are ordered 1,3,5,10,5, and the importance is ordered 8,7,7,8,3. So sorting by distance or importance is obviously *not* the answer.

Comment: Yes, as i mentioned i am aware that neither of those are the optimal solution. The optimal solution should take into consideration both factors. I guess there is a formula for such problems

Comment: one heuristic could be sort by ratio of importance/distance in decreasing order, and calculate answer. It gives 323 as @user3386109 has said. But ofcourse it is greedy, I don't have the proof. I came with the ratio as since we want to reduce total cost, we want the important to come as early as possible but we also want the less distant ones first for minimizing cost.

Comment: Possible explanation for my approach: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/98437/correctness-proof-for-greedy-algorithm-based-on-ratio

Comment: You just saved me another half of an hour of juggling with indices. I had it almost written down, however I forgot that division existed and started getting a wee bit tangled. ^^.

Comment: It seems that you're attempting to minimize something ("lateness" in this case) based on a series of constraints (distance and importance). Sounds like a linear programming problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note:** neither of the greedy approaches that you mentioned results in an optimal solution. 
Behold this order:

```
 CUSTOMER       DISTANCE        IMPORTANCE
 2              1               8
 5              3               7
 3              5               7
 1              10              8
 4              5               3
```

With the resulting sum of 323. This happens because `10 * 3 = 30 < 40 = 5 * 8`.
The question becomes: Can we build on top of this observation?

### Starting from the simple:

Lets look at the case of only two customers:

```
c1    d1    i1
c2    d2    i2
```

If we take c1 first, its **cost** will be `d1 * i1`. At the same time, he will increase the cost of every subsequent customer **cx** by  `cx * d1`. The same works the other way around for the customer c2. Which one do we pick first then? 
c1 first: `c1_sum = d1 * i1 + (d1 + d2) * i2 = d1 * i1 + d1 * i2 + d2 * i2` 
c2 first: `c2_sum = d2 * i2 + (d1 + d2) * i1 = d2 * i2 + d1 * i1 + d2 * i1` 
`d1 * i1` appears in both sums. Same for `d2 * i2`. The only difference is the `d1 * i2` vs `d2 * i1`. This means that **c1_sum < c2_sum** <=> **d1 * i2 < d2 * i1**.

#### Moving towards the solution:

Now let us consider the original task with multiple customers c1, ... cn. The customer **ck** should have priority if for every other customer **cl (l=0..n, l != k)** this is true: **dk * il < dl * ik**.

**Why is that?**
For a customer, the only thing that matters is the sum of times of the preceding customers since his own time * importance score is fixed. So we will want to compare how much we will hold up the other customers as opposed to holding this single customer.

**Do we have to recompute everything at every step?**
If at every step, we have to compute this comparison for every pair of elements, we would be in the not-so-nice territory of O(n<sup>3</sup>). Polynomial complexity is manageable, however 3 in the exponent is rather annoying and it would be for the best if we could prevent it. For example by ordering the nodes.<sup>1</sup> Can we do that?

- **Reflexivity:** Holds.
- **Antisymmetry:** If **dk * il = dl * ik** it means that **dk * il < dl * ik** which is equivalent to **(dk / ik) < (dl / il)**
- **Transitivity** similarly to the previous step.

**Note:** kudos to @รยקคгรђשค, I forgot that the division existed and got wee bit tangled in the indices.

So since the relation is an order, we can sort by it. Sort is O(n log(n)) and then we can just grab the pieces greedily in order.

---

<sup>1</sup> By the **distance / importance** ratio.

Comment: Nice answer! Would be good to assert that the ordering should be done by the ratio of distance to importance (dk/ik) so it's clear.